# What is the meaning of Motzkin's theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, decision-problems

> **Theorem:** Let $A$ and $C$ be two matrices. The system of linear inequalities $Ax<0$ and $Cx \leq 0$ has a solution iff the following equation in $\lambda$ and $\mu$ does not have a solution$$A^T \lambda + C^T \mu =0$$ where $\lambda \geq 0$, $\lambda \neq 0$, $\mu \geq 0$.

What is the meaning of the $\lambda \geq 0$ and $\lambda \neq 0$ part? why not write $\lambda > 0$?

I am confused! Is there an elementary proof of this theorem?

Comment: $\lambda \geq 0$ and $\lambda \neq 0$ means that each element of the vector $\lambda$ is greater than or equal to 0 and that at least one element of the vector is not 0.  This is not the same as saying that all elements of the vector are greater than 0.